# Get GeoLocation in Xamarin.Forms when not conencted to Internet

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, geolocation

I am using `Xam.Plugin.GeoLocator` from [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) to get the geo location of a user in Xamarin.Forms project. This is working great when the device is connected to Internet. I need to capture the Lat/Long coordinates of the user when the device is not connected to Internet.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Use last known latitude/longitude, store somewhere (for example use Settings plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin, etc.)

Comment: That's the last resort. Any way to get the coordinates from hardware GPS or via triangulation method?

Comment: Does your device have a GPS?

Comment: Yes, I think so, atleast the vendor says so . How do I check that?

Comment: @Nitesh In terms of Android, if you have Location Services enabled, but no Internet and/or Cellular, the GeoLocator plugin will return what the OS supplies. It can be the GPS-based location **IF** the device is able to make a connection to multiple satellites (i.e. turn on airplane mode, go outside with an unobstructed view of about 1/5 of the sky, open Google maps/Waze/etc.. and your current location on the map will be updated.).

Comment: @SushiHangover Does that mean GeoLocator will auto return the GPS co-ordinates even if the mobile is not connected to Internet?

Comment: @Nitesh The GeoLocator returns what the OS supplies, so yes, if you have no cellular/wifi but the device does have a GPS connection, then that is what is returned. i.e. If you request a *high/fine* accuracy than the GPS might be used instead of Google's location services using the cellular or wifi connections even if they are available. Same basically for iOS, but using Apple location services...

Answer (score 1):

As per comments above, The `GeoLocator` plugin returns what the OS supplies, so yes, if you have no cellular/wifi but the device does have a GPS connection, then that is what is returned. i.e. If you request a high/fine accuracy than the GPS might be used instead of Google's location services using the cellular or wifi connections even if they are available. Same basically for iOS, but using Apple location services.